# Por que fgetc(stdin) não reconhece o fim de um arquivo?

Tags: c

Por algum motivo o `fgetc(stdin)` não está reconhecendo o fim de linha de um arquivo e ele fica no `while` infinitamente.

```
fscanf(arqIN, "%*s %d", &qntPacientes); // Aqui é só pra pegar a informação da primeira linha
    
    pacientes = (Paciente**)malloc(qntPacientes * sizeof(Paciente*));
    
    if (pacientes == NULL){exit(1);}
    
    while(endF != 1) {
        index = 0;
        fscanf(arqIN, "%d", &atualPaciente);
        printf("Paciente: %d ", atualPaciente);
        
        while (ch = fgetc(arqIN) != '\n') {
            
            fscanf(arqIN, "%d", &resultados[index]);
            printf("%d ", resultados[index]);
            index++;
            tamanhoVetorResultados++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        
        pacientes[atualPaciente] = retornaResultados(resultados, tamanhoVetorResultados);
        
        if(ch == EOF) {endF = 1;}
    }
```

O arquivo de entrada está assim:

```
Clientes: 4
2 110 120 100 300 110
3 250
1 170 100
0 95
```

Comment: Será que aqui: `while (ch = fgetc(arqIN) != '\n') {` você não queria fazer `while ((ch = fgetc(arqIN)) != '\n') {`? Verifique a prioridade dos operadores.

Comment: Fiz a troca e mesmo assim continua infinitamente no loop

Comment: Neste teste https://ideone.com/8RmeUy funcionou como o esperado.

Comment: Eu parei para testar aqui, e no VSCode deu um resultado diferente do onlineGDB(No caso deu certo no VSCode).